# Python socket programming recv

Tags: python, ubuntu

I've started with python today and i'm looking into socket programming atm. Ive connected to an ip and port with a socket instance and im trying to read the next 1024 bytes on the socket with the recv method. When im trying to store it in a variable, I get an error telling me that the socket times out, tried increasing it but didn't help.

Code:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
>>> s = socket.socket()
>>> s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21))
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Comment: You are unable to connect on port 21 according to what you show here. You never get to the part where you read the socket. Make sure the server has something running on that port.

Comment: I would start with the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html

Comment: Port 21 is used by FTP. Is FTP running on the machine to which you are trying to connect ? If no, is there any other service or server running on that port, which can accept your connect() call.

Comment: Try to connect to the IP and port with netcat or telnet

Answer (score 0):

You set a timeout in `socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)`, therefore it raises an exception.

Try this instead:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
socket.setdefaulttimeout(10) #set timeout for ten seconds (can be whatever you want)
try:
    s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21))
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occured:\n{}".format(e))
```